# Regex to parse package name and version number from nuget package filenames

Tags: regex, nuget, nuget-package

I have a directory of nuget packages that I've downloaded from nuget.org. I'm trying to create a regex that will parse out the package name and version number from the filename. It doesn't seem difficult at first glance; the filenames have a clear pattern:

`{PackageName}.{VersionNumber}.nupkg`

Edge cases make it challenging though.

- Package names can have dashes, underscores, and numbers
- Package names can have effectively unlimited parts separated by dots
- Version numbers consist of 3-4 groups of numbers, separated by dots
- Version numbers sometimes are suffixed with pre-release tags (-alpha, -beta, etc)

---

Here's a sample list of nuget package filenames:

```
knockoutjs.3.4.2.nupkg
log4net.2.0.8.nupkg
runtime.tizen.4.0.0-armel.microsoft.netcore.jit.2.0.0.nupkg
nuget.core.2.7.0-alpha.nupkg
microsoft.identitymodel.6.1.7600.16394.nupkg
```

I want to be able to do a search/replace in a Serious Text Editor where the search is a regex with two groups, one for the package name and one for the version number. The output should be "Package: \1 Version: \2". With the 5 packages above, the output should be:

```
Package: knockoutjs Version: 3.4.2
Package: log4net Version: 2.0.8
Package: runtime.tizen.4.0.0-armel.microsoft.netcore.jit Version: 2.0.0
Package: nuget.core Version: 2.7.0-alpha
Package: microsoft.identitymodel Version: 6.1.7600.16394
```

---

The closest relatively concise regex I've come up with is:

```
^([^\s]*)\.((?:[0-9]+\.){3,})nupkg$
```

...which results in the following output:

```
Package: knockoutjs Version: 3.4.2.
Package: log4net Version: 2.0.8.
Package: runtime.tizen.4.0.0-armel.microsoft.netcore.jit Version: 2.0.0.
nuget.core.2.7.0-alpha.nupkg
Package: microsoft.identitymodel.6 Version: 1.7600.16394.
```

It handles the first three decently, although I don't want that trailing dot. It doesn't even match on the fourth one, and the fifth one has the first part of the version number lumped in with the package name.

[Save the day!](https://xkcd.com/208/)

Comment: [No guarantees that this will match everything, but give it a try and let me know](https://regex101.com/r/nJBIAB/1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I modified your expression slightly to:

```
^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$
```

The main points are that I moved the `.` in front of the digits in the first non capturing group, and that I added an optional non capturing group for `-alpha` in the fourth string.

Replace with:

```
Package: \1 Version: \2
```

Test the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/SNMsqI/1).

Comment: This is great. Could you explain how the regex engine is processing that first '?' that makes '.*' optional? Without that first '?', your regex works in every case but the last. The last case ends up outputting: "Package: microsoft.identitymodel.6.1.7600 Version: 16394". I know '?' to be a greedy operator, so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why adding it here seems to make it .* less greedy.

Comment: Ah ha. The ? operator in that context doesn't mean optional, it makes the * operator lazy instead of greedy. https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: @BobbyA That is correct, it will try to match as few as possible.`.?` is different than `.*?`.

Comment: ^(?<packageID>.*?)\.(?<version>(?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$ adding named groups

Comment: I had a similar use cases but the above regex was failing for the following (super-weird) use-cases:

Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3.1.0.0-beta4-1.nupkg
rhinomocks.3.6.nupkg

So I adjusted it slightly:
^(.*?)\.((?:\.?v?[0-9]+){2,}(?:[-a-z0-9]+)?)\.nupkg$ 

This seems to match all my packages now.

Comment: wont work if you have dot notation after the prerelease, e.g. nuget.core.2.7.0-alpha.123.nupkg

Comment: @Leon is that package actually a valid one?

Comment: [of course](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html#spec-item-9), with other examples: 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-0.3.7, 1.0.0-x.7.z.92, 1.0.0-x-y-z.--.

Comment: @Leon how about https://regex101.com/r/u4iRKw/1 ?

Comment: still does not work correctly - "nuget.core.1.0.0-x.alpha.123-y.nupkg" does not work, also "nuget.core.1.0.0-x+123.nupkg". You can [try here](https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/#/1.*/nuget.core.1.0.0-x.alpha.123-y.nupkg)

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex will do what you want:

```
^(.*?)\.(?=(?:[0-9]+\.){2,}[0-9]+(?:-[a-z]+)?\.nupkg)(.*?)\.nupkg$
```

It uses a positive lookahead to look for the version number followed (possibly) by a tag in the form `-[a-z]+` (e.g. `-alpha`) followed by `\.nupkg`. This last part prevents it matching the `4.0.0-armel` in the third sample. For your edge cases, and substituting with `Package: $1 Version: $2` the output is:

```
Package: knockoutjs Version: 3.4.2
Package: log4net Version: 2.0.8
Package: runtime.tizen.4.0.0-armel.microsoft.netcore.jit Version: 2.0.0
Package: nuget.core Version: 2.7.0-alpha
Package: microsoft.identitymodel Version: 6.1.7600.16394
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l7ZSMM/2/)

Answer (score 1):

To include the entire version, everything before ".nupkg":

```
^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z0-9]+?\.?)*)\.nupkg$
```

This gives these groups for `My.Package.1.2.3.4-pre.1.other-thing`:

1. `My.Package`
2. `1.2.3.4-pre.1.other-thing`