# A regex for NPM or any other package both for name and any version number

Tags: javascript, regex

I search on SO and on google a good validation regex to detect **FULL** NPM / other package name (package name(@)version number - all formats).
Now, before you mark this question as duplicate, I must say I searched over here and none of what I found has worked for me:
[Regex to parse package name and version number from nuget package filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662737/regex-to-parse-package-name-and-version-number-from-nuget-package-filenames)
[A regex for version number parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing)

[npm/validate-npm-package-name](https://github.com/npm/validate-npm-package-name)

[Semantic versioning regex](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/62eeea161a13b80e39f5249281e17c39)

[package-name-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-name-regex)

[semver-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver-regex)

I also tried a couple of regex myself but none of them do the work for any edge case:

```
const regex = new RegExp(/(\^|\~?)(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+/g);
const isScriptVersion = regex.test('imagesloaded@4.1');
if (isScriptVersion) {
}
```

or

```
const regex = new RegExp('^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)');
console.log(regex.test('imagesloaded@4.1'));
```

Also tried with 3th party NPM packages but not so luck:

```
const packageNameRegex = require('package-name-regex')
console.log(packageNameRegex.test('font-awesome@5.11.2'))

const semverRegex = require('semver-regex');
console.log(semverRegex().test('font-awesome@5.11.2'));
```

Here is my test list:

```
ansi-escapes@^4.3.1
babel-eslint@^10.1.0
chance@^1.1.7
cli-cursor@^3.1.0
eslint@^7.13.0
faker@^5.1.0
forever-monitor@^3.0.1
fs-extra@^9.0.1
lorem-ipsum@^2.0.3
micromatch@^4.0.2
mongoose@^5.10.13
puppeteer@^5.4.1
puppeteer-extra@^3.1.15
puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth@^2.6.3
random-email@^1.0.3
random-useragent@^0.5.0
random-words@^1.1.1
slice-ansi@^4.0.0
uuid@^8.3.1
validator@13.1.17
wrap-ansi@^7.0.0
font-awesome@5.11.2
react-dom@16.13.1
bootstrap@4.5.2
moment-duration-format@2.3.2
```

All of the above work with

```
/(\^|\~?)(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+/g
```

**However** 
The following don't work for me:

```
imagesloaded@4.1
flickity@2.0
lomster@1
example@1.1.1.1.1
example-package@3.12.45.66.34.2
unicorn@1.2.3-alpha.10.beta.0
rainbow@v1.1.1
```

Many thanks to you all. Cheers.

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp`, just use a regex literal. Especially your second attempt uses a string literal where the backslashes are not escaped.

Comment: Did you take a look at the source codes of `package-name-regex` and `semver-regex` and try to combine their regular expressions into one? Alternatively you could split on the `@` character (of which there should only be one…) and test for package name and semver string separately.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the comments. anubhava already solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
/@[~^]?([\dvx*]+(?:[-.](?:[\dx*]+|alpha|beta))*)/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uOCqua/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `@`: Match a `@`
- `[~^]?`: Match an optional `~` or `^`
- `(`: Start a capture group #1

  - `[\dvx*]+`: Match 1+ of digit or `v` or `x` or `*` characters
  - `(?:` Start a non-capture group

    - `[-.]`: Match a `-` or `.`
    - `(?:[\dx*]+|alpha|beta)`: Match 1+ of digit or `v` or `x` or `*` characters or `alpha` or `beta`
  - `)*`: End non-capture group. `*` means match 0 or more of this group
- `)`: End capture group #1