# Parse nuget package name and version from .nupkg file in Linux

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to parse a .nupkg filename like "foo.12.1.2.nupkg" in a Linux shell. I am trying to capture the groups and store the package name inside variable `package_name` and store the version inside variable `version`. In this example, `package_name` should be "foo" and `version` should be "12.1.2". I am using the regex `^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$` that is referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662737/regex-to-parse-package-name-and-version-number-from-nuget-package-filenames).

Here is the code:

```
string="foo.12.4.1.nupkg"
regex='^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$'

if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]; then
  package_name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  package_version=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  echo "Package name: $package_name"
  echo "Package version: $package_version"
else
  echo "String does not match regex"
fi
```

However, this always prints `String does not match regex`.

I even tried to break it down into the following combinations:

```
> regex=^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$
> string=foo.12.4.1.nupkg
> [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo "matched" || echo "not matched"
```

or

```
> regex='^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$'
> string='foo.12.4.1.nupkg'
> [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo "matched" || echo "not matched"
```

or

```
> regex='^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$'
> string=foo.12.4.1.nupkg
> [[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo "matched" || echo "not matched"
```

or

```
> regex='^(.*?)\.((?:\.?[0-9]+){3,}(?:[-a-z]+)?)\.nupkg$'
> string=foo.12.4.1.nupkg
> [[ ${string} =~ ${regex} ]] && echo "matched" || echo "not matched"
```

I am always getting "not matched" as the output. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I've looked everywhere and still cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: You'll need to adapt the regex work in bash. Bash uses [POSIX extended regex syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions), which is not as capable as regexes in most other languages. Notably, `?:` to disable capture groups is not supported.

Comment: I am completely new to regex could you please provide the bash adapted syntax for this same regex if possible?

Comment: Good time to learn it then!

Comment: Consider having `awk` (and shell parameter editing) parse you "string", i.e. `pkgNameVer=$(awk -F"." '{print $1 ":" $2"."$3"."$4}'<<< $string);  pkg=${pkgNameVer%%:*};ver=${
pkgNameVer#*:} ; echo $pkg $ver $pkgNameVer`  ... Good luck.

Comment: @shellter This wouldn't work for a filename like "Azure.Storage.Blobs.5.2.1.nupkg".

Comment: You can't ask people to write a regex for you, if you don't also **define** how exactly your filename looks like. You give only one example for such a filename and _shelter_ gives i his comment a solution working for this filename. Now you can come up with a completely different name. Why do you think that this would work with the new name as well?

Comment: @CSKid : I worked with what you gave me (-; Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
regex='^(.*)\.(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,})[-a-z]*)\.nupkg$'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/U7oa3Z):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
regex='^(.*)\.(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,})[-a-z]*)\.nupkg$'
string=foo.12.4.1.nupkg
[[ $string =~ $regex ]] && echo "matched" || echo "not matched"
```

Output: `true`.

*Note*:

- All capturing groups are either removed if not necessary (`(?:[-a-z]+)?` => `[-a-z]*`) or converted to capturing (as POSIX regex does not support the former)
- As lazy quantifiers are not supported, `.*?` is replaced with `.*` (in the current regex, it seams reasonable since you only need to stop at the last 3 or more dot-separated numbers).